# Wordpress: Sort posts chronologically by custom field

Tags: wordpress, date, field

I have some posts used as events, with a custom field for the event's date. I'm looking for ordering thoses posts by event's date (chronologically). 
I'm wondering:

- Is it possible to set the event's date custom field as a "date" format
  (for now, it's a simple type=text).
- Howto order thoses posts if i always
  use the same format (like
  dd/mm/yyyy). I need to get the 3 close coming events (not the last 3).

Did wordpress has a built-in function who could compare a date to the today's date?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this! (www.wherewordsgo.com)

okay, i only got it working for 'pages' but.

but if you make a meta box for 'deadline' and then put the date in yyyy/mm/dd format and add this to your functions.php it might help:

add_action('wp', 'check_page');
function check_page () {
    if (is_page()) {
        add_filter('get_previous_post_sort', 'sort_it');
        add_filter('get_next_post_sort', 'sort_it');
        add_filter('posts_orderby', 'sort_it' );
        add_filter('posts_join', 'join_it' );
        add_filter('posts_where', 'where_it' );

```
    function sort_it () {
        global $wpdb;

        return " $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC ";
    }

    function join_it( $join ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id) ";

      return $join;
    }

    function where_it( $where ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $where .= "AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'deadline' ";

      return $where;
    }
}
```

I got that from some site (which I have lost the link for... big WP dude though I think) and changed it as needed. Like I said it works only for custom pages on my build (I'm using a custom type), but may well just work for everything if you change the 'is_page()' function at the start to whatever is relative for you.

Hope that helps